# How do I extract a list of files that are failing to sync on Backup and Sync on windows?

Tags: windows, windows-10, google-backup-and-sync

We've had some sync problems recently, and i've over 1000 files that Backup and Sync "Can't Sync".
Unfortunately the UI is very unhelpful and only displays 10 records at a time, and even then you can't copy and paste the list.

How can I extract this list easily into a text file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've discovered that all the problem files are logged in the sync_log.log file, located in
C:\Users<User>\AppData\Local\Google\Drive\user_default\sync_log.log

To get a clear list, note the time stamp of last entry in the log, then retry all failures.
If you only work with the newly created entries in the log then the lines containing "blacklist.py" will all mention the file that is missing.

Maybe someone more skilled at unix style parsing can figure a way to cleanly extract file names, but for me i can slice and dice away at the log entries using Notepad++